# Using fosJsRouting and Assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm trying to use fosJsRouting with ascetic but I have a problem.

Before I was Including:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

And now I ran:

```
$ php app/console fos:js-routing:dump
```

and I add

```
{% javascripts filter='?yui_js'
    'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
    'js/fos_js_routes.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But for all of my routes I have this error:

```
Error: The route "test_route" does not exist.
```

My code works when I include the code without using assetics.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, wueh you include the scripts without assetc, the "fos_js_routing_js" route has a callback. This callback take all js routes and push them in the js Router component. 
When you include you generated files in assetic, this callback is never called, so the Router is never aware of the js routes.

I think there is no simple solution to use assetic and JmsJsRouting together.

Comment: I take the documentation code, il should works https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md